Karabiner Elements: Using sticky modifier keys without a delay?
When I map a modifier to sticky_right_control, my complex modification below doesn't work without pressing the non-modifier key at least twice or waiting (h or j in this case). How can the delay be removed, and have it work either when I press it once or while holding it down?
{
    "description": "Ctrl + h j k l to Arrow Keys",
    "manipulators": [
        {
            "from": {
                "key_code": "h",
                "modifiers": { "mandatory": ["right_control"] }
            },
            "to": [{ "key_code": "left_arrow" }],
            "type": "basic"
        },
        {
            "from": {
                "key_code": "j",
                "modifiers": {
                    "mandatory": ["right_control"],
                    "optional": ["any"]
                }
            },
            "to": [{ "key_code": "down_arrow" }],
            "type": "basic"
        }
    ]
}

